# Rails form : AssociationTypeMismatch in form with select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I try to make a connection between a Match and 2 Players in a form where we can select the players from the list of the players registered:

```
<%= f.label :"Joueur 1" %>
<%= f.select :playerone, @players.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]} , class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :"Joueur 2" %>
<%= f.select :playertwo, @players.collect {|b| [b.name, b.id]} , class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :Prolongations %>
<%= f.check_box :prolongations %><br />

<%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

The schema of tables :  with a Join Table Matches Players

```
create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "prolongations"
end

create_table "matches_players", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "match_id", null: false
    t.integer "player_id", null: false
    t.index ["match_id", "player_id"], name: "index_matches_players_on_match_id_and_player_id"
    t.index ["player_id", "match_id"], name: "index_matches_players_on_player_id_and_match_id"
end

create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "points"
end
```

In matches.controller :

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController
    attr_accessor :player_id, :playerone, :playertwo

def new
    @match= Match.new
    @players = Player.all
end

def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)

    @players = Player.all
    if @match.save
        flash[:success] = "Votre match a bien été enregistré !"
        redirect_to @match
    else
        render 'new'
        p "Une erreur existe, veuillez recommencer."
    end    
end

def show
    @match = Match.find(params[:id])
end

private
    def match_params
params.require(:match).permit(:prolongations, :playerone, :playertwo)

end
end
```

And in the Match model :

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :teams , class_name: "Team"
    belongs_to :playerone, class_name: "Player" ,foreign_key: "player_id"
    belongs_to :playertwo, class_name: "Player" ,foreign_key: "player_id"
end
```

And the result when I submit my form is :

> **Player(#69852298534200) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#4817000)**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>".............",
 "match"=>{"playerone"=>"1", "playertwo"=>"3", "prolongations"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Enregistrer le match"}
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is just to use `playerone_id`  and `playertwo_id` as the param keys (change the name of the inputs). If you use `playerone` the setter expects the argument to be an instance of Player - not a string containing an id.

Which will fix the immediate issue but there is a much better way to solve it.

Start by setting up a [real many to many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :player_matches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :players, through: :player_matches
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :player_matches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matches, through: :player_matches
end

class PlayerMatches < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match
end
```

This lets you avoid a very awkward issue when you set two belongs to associations to the same table where the associated record can be in either column:

```
Match.find_by("(playerone_id = :a OR playertwo_id = :a) AND (playerone_id = :b OR playertwo_id = :b)", a: a, b: b)
```

Yeah thats how you have to query for a match between players. Joins can be even more messy.

With that setup you can simply assign players to a match by:

```
@match.player_ids = [1,2]
```

Which is exactly what you can do with the [collection helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease):

```
<%= form_for(@match) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :player_ids, "Select the players" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :player_ids, Player.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

All you have to do on the controller side is whitelist `player_ids`:

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @match = Match.new(match_params)
    # ...
  end

  def update
    if @match.update(match_params)
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

    def match_params
      params.require(:match).permit(:foo, :bar, player_ids: [])
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want to limit a match to two players then create a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).